# Most efficient way to do RPC on the HoloLens 2

Tags: grpc, rpc, hololens

I need to do some low-volume but moderately high frequency RPC between a PC and the HoloLens 2 via local WiFi and I'm currently using GRPC (which you have to compile yourself for ARM64) but I'm running into severe performance bottlenecks. For instance, the HoloLens is unable to cope with mouse input data it receives at more than 15fps. Are REST-based RPC APIs better supported?

Comment: What grpc language are you using? Probably raising an issue on the appropriate grpc repository on Github (with additional details) would get some eyes on the issue.

Comment: There's no official ARM64 binary for grpc and you need to do quite some work to get the code to compile for that architecture (as explained in [this thread](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/23488)), which is what I did. Considering it's been 2 years there's been no progress on grpc support for the HoloLens I doubt it's suddenly going to happen if I add a message or an issue there. Hence my question was more about viable alternatives using APIs that officially support the HoloLens or at least have been extensively tested on the device.